# How to get the first element from a parent in several places

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div class="fullNews"> 
  <div class="mainText">
     <a href="news-16.jpg"><img src="/contentthumbs/news-16_thumb.jpg"></a> 
     <a href="news-17.jpg"><img src="/contentthumbs/news-17_thumb.jpg"></a> 
     <a href="news-18.jpg"><img src="/contentthumbs/news-18_thumb.jpg"></a> 
     <a href="news-19.jpg"><img src="/contentthumbs/news-19_thumb.jpg"></a> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fullNews"> 
  <div class="mainText">
     <a href="news-20.jpg"><img src="/contentthumbs/news-20_thumb.jpg"></a> 
     <a href="news-21.jpg"><img src="/contentthumbs/news-21_thumb.jpg"></a> 
     <a href="news-22.jpg"><img src="/contentthumbs/news-22_thumb.jpg"></a> 
     <a href="news-23.jpg"><img src="/contentthumbs/news-23_thumb.jpg"></a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to apply a CSS class to only the first hyperlinks of each lot of parent divs through JQuery:

```
$('.mainText a:first').addClass('mainPhoto');
```

But it only adds the class to the first hyperlink of the first div group. I need that all the first hyperlinks of each `<div class="mainText">` get the class, in this example:

```
 <a href="news-16.jpg">
 <a href="news-20.jpg">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**first-child Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/), it selects all elements that are the first child of their parent. While [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) matches only a single element

```
 $('.mainText a:first-child').addClass('mainPhoto');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/HTmQL/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Why jQuery? use pure CSS:

```
.mainText a:first-child {
    <your properties>
}
```

---

About your jQuery error:

you have used `:first` that is not a CSS selector but a jQuery selector, that matches only the first matching element.
You should instead use `:first-child` that is a CSS selector and will select each first-children matched.

Answer (score 1):

In case of you want to do it with only javascript, then use this code.

```
var allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("mainText");
for(var i=0; i<allDivs.length; i++){
    //firstElementChild referes the first element of div
   allDivs[i].firstElementChild.className = 'mainPhoto';    
}
```

Demo you can on http://jsfiddle.net/7DS5F/19/

Comment: This way also worked, but I prefer the jquery one :) Thanks for the support!